# Expectation of maxima of $n$ Erlang-distributed (Gamma-distributed) random variables for small $n$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, order-statistics, gamma-distribution, extreme-value-analysis

Say I have $n$ i.i.d. random variables $\mathbf{X}_n = \{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$, where $X_i \sim \operatorname{Erlang}(k,\theta)$  or $\Gamma(k,\theta)$.

Define $$Z_n := \max \mathbf{X}_n$$

I know that $Z_n$ is in the domain of attraction of the Gumbel distribution [as shown in e.g. the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063275/is-there-an-equation-for-the-maximum-of-n-random-draws-from-a-gamma-distribution)

But it seems that the sequence converges rather slowly (at least for the normalizing constants given in the above link), most likely too slow for my purposes.

---

I've modeled the time it takes for $n$ parallel sequences of $k$ tasks to finish as $n$ Gamma-distributed random variables. Assuming all tasks are i.i.d. exponentially distributed. And want to know the time it takes for all sequences to finish, the maximum.

My $n$'s are the sequence of powers of two, which start off very small, and therefore not that close to a denormalized Gumbel. These small powers of two are however still of interest.

I can of course use the exact distribution for some specific $n$, i.e.

$$E(Z_n) = \int_0^\infty xf_{Z_n}(x) \, \text{d} x$$

But $f_{Z_n}$ looks rather unsavory:

$$f_{Z_n}(x) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left( 1 - \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{e^{-\theta x}(\theta x)^n}{n!}\right)^m\\
= \frac{\theta m e^{-\theta x}(\theta x)^{k-1}\left(1 -\frac{(k-1)!\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\frac{e^{-\theta x}(\theta x)^l}{l!} }{k!}\right)^{m-1}}{k!}$$

(can also be expressed with gamma functions) and I can't seem to get a very clean result for the expectation of $Z_n$. I am however but an engineer and not that great at complicated integrals. This does seem to graph out a rather regular-looking curve, as seen in [the question I linked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063275/is-there-an-equation-for-the-maximum-of-n-random-draws-from-a-gamma-distribution), so maybe this could be solved (at least numerically for specific Gamma-distributions).

It would be nice to have a general distribution, with a known expectation, which the GEV-distribution gives. The only trouble is the rather large errors to the exact distribution for small $n$.

---

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a clean way to represent the expectation of the exact distribution of the max of $n$ Gamma distributed random variables?
2. Is there a better way to pick the normalizing constants so that the normalized Gumbel converges towards the exact distribution quicker?
3. Is there any information about the rate of convergence for Gumbel-distributions and their domains of attraction? Or the error as a function of $n$?

Comment: Do you want just a decent approximation for $EZ_n$ or you are interested in the entire distribution of $Z_n$?

Comment: The entire distribution would of course be interesting, but $E(Z_n)$ is what I really need.